# How to sum functions in MATLAB under a condition

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a function that sums a bunch of functions and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. My code:

```
function [f_max,x_max] = ftot(l,a,E,J,F)
% a and F are arrays

f_max = 0;

b = l-a;
n = length(F);
f1 = 0;
syms x
for j=1:n
y1 = piecewise(x<=a(j),1,x>a(j),0);
y2 = piecewise(x<=a(j),0,x>a(j),1);
f = (F(j)*b(j)*x)*y1 + (F(j)*b(j)*x^3)*y2;
f1 = f1 + f;
end
```

Basically I want to create a function that is the sum of `F(j)*b(j)*x` for `j=1:n` when `x<=a` and `F(j)*b(j)*x^3` when `x>a`. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Please improve your question by adding the missing information. What are `l, E, J`? What is the size of `F` and `a`? What are `f_max` and `x_max`? There is no mention of any of them at all. Hopefully, if you can't write the code, upload the equation as an image and give the typical values of all variables. People here can give you solid advice if you provide them with enough information about your problem.

Comment: Besides the comment above about clarifying what the inputs are, you need to tell us what is wrong with your code: does it produce wrong results, does it error out, does it not produce an output at all? If there’s an error message, copy-paste it into your question. Read [mre], then [edit] your post.